Solaan transaction delay
Is there any way that after a wallet signs a transaction I can delay the transaction from actually going through until I call a function or is this not possible, also open to work arounds.
Thanks in advance.

It's not possible natively unfortunately. If you want to sign a transaction and then send it later, you can use a nonce account to keep the signature valid indefinitely https://solana.com/docs/clients/javascript-reference#nonceaccount
But after that, you'll need to trust a service to hold the signature and send it later. Once the transaction is signed, it's valid to be used anytime.
